# Why can't I join my friend's LAN game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have my boyfriend added as a friend on Xbox Live, and we've played Minecraft before in the past, but now we haven't been able to for the past two weeks. His games are set online, we're connected to the same WiFi, and both worlds will show up in the friends section. But for some reason neither of us can join the other's game. Why is this happening and can I fix it?

Comment: What's the error when you try to join? Are you doing so via LAN? If  so, is the world being opened to LAN?

Comment: Which game are you actually playing, MCJava or MCBE? And @Joachim, why did you edit out the MCJava tag? Do you have any external information about this case? If yes, why didn't you comment about it?

Comment: @FabianRöling I thought the Bedrock Edition was the only one available through a Microsoft account. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Joachim I have no idea how MCBE accounts work. So you might be right. Still, @ Princess Panda, please only use tags that apply.

Comment: @FabianRöling I edited out the OP's comment about the use of tags, as they were looking for non-existing (and incorrect) ones.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this. Your connection might not be strong enough to actually play online, or it could be an issue with Minecraft itself.

First you should check Minecraft for any updates as you cannot play with other players across different versions/updates.

Comment: If versions is the issue, then it will still appear but when you attempt to connect it will say "outdated client" or "outdated server"